# What does renunciation of scholarship mean?

Tags: funding, quitting, withdraw

I want to know what renunciation of scholarship mean? Is it the same as withdrawing from a scholarship program? Which one is better to quit a scholarship?
Does renunciation of scholarship form enables a person to re apply to a scholarship again?

Comment: It depends on context. It could be anything from a person withdrawing from the scolarly community/profession, to a funding body declaring they will not offer a scholarship (funding) this year/again, to a person declining scholarship funding after previously accepting it (which they might do for any number of reasons -- from withdrawing from university, to (scandalously) being shown to not have been eligible in the first place, to protesting the actions of the funding body).

Comment: What's the context? Who uses the expression in a situation that is relevant to you personally?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend upon the specific rules of the funding agency and at what point you are renouncing the scholarship.

For example, I renounced a Ph.D grant from one agency before starting any further commitment because at the time of the results I already had received funding from another agency. In this case there was no drawback.

In Portugal you are able to renounce a Ph.D grant at latest 1 year after the start without penalties. However, after the first year if you renounce the grant and are not intending to finish the Ph.D the funding agency will demand the reimbursement of their investment on you.

For a more specific answer you should look at the rules of the particular scholarship that you have interest.